# Python virtualenv SSL error under root user

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, virtualenv

On Ubuntu 14.04, I install python, pip, setuptools, virtualenv (as root).

As a regular user, I run

```
$ pip list
apt-xapian-index (0.45)
chardet (2.0.1)
pip (8.0.2)
python-apt (0.9.3.5ubuntu2)
python-debian (0.1.21-nmu2ubuntu2)
requests (2.2.1)
setuptools (19.7)
six (1.5.2)
ssh-import-id (3.21)
urllib3 (1.7.1)
virtualenv (14.0.5)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:315: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:120: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
```

And then I can create a virtualenv

```
$ virtualenv fooenv
```

And everything is right with the world! The problem comes about that if I switch to root user and try to create a virtual environment

```
$ sudo su -
$ virtualenv fooenv
New python executable in /root/fooenv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
  Complete output from command /root/fooenv/bin/python -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip wheel:
  Collecting setuptools
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:315: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:120: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/basecommand.py", line 209, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/commands/install.py", line 299, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_set.py", line 359, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/req/req_set.py", line 576, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/download.py", line 809, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/download.py", line 648, in unpack_http_url
    hashes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/download.py", line 841, in _download_http_url
    stream=True,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 480, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/download.py", line 377, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 46, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv_support/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 447, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
SSLError: [Errno 185090050] _ssl.c:344: error:0B084002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 703, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 904, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 861, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 781, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /root/fooenv/bin/python -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 2
```

So what gives? Why can my regular user create a virtualenv, but not my root user?

Comment: Seems like an obscure bug. Anyway, I'd try installing package "certifi" first to eliminate nagging suspicion it's just (maybe) lack of proper CA certs. P.S. this message "A true SSLContext object is not available." suggests there *might* be something wrong with your openssl installation anyway.

Comment: Eh, I gave up. Since I'm using the python version installed by Ubuntu, I looked in the package index and installed python-virtualenv & python-pip via apt-get. They are not the latest versions, but they work.